# Links in Excel changed after a crash

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office, symbolic-link

A few of my users use Excel spreadsheets that have cells linked to other spread sheats. It is set up so the **catering.xslx** pints to the **inventory,comm2002.xls**. I was told that excel will crash and all the links will be messed up. In one case it defaulted to the C: drive in another case it was set to the H: drive (which is the correct drive letter)But it was pointing to a excel file in that directory. (with a totalt different name)

These files are used by a few people and some are running in office 2003 SP3 and some are running Office 2007.

So I am wondering, Is there a way to prevent this from happening.
And, is it possible to fix this in the event it does happen. Thanks.

Comment: Wouldn't that be a nice question for superuser.com?

Comment: No, I think that server fault relates to everything System Administration which this falls under.

Comment: Well, there's gotta be a line somewhere.  Application support is a fantastic topic for SU.  Use ewok.adventure as the password to join the beta.

Comment: Sounds like a perfect candidate for putting into a database somewhere rather than keep in Excel spreadsheets.

Comment: Thats kinda what I was thinking, but I thought I would see if anyone else had any thoughts. I work for a consulting company so as you can imagine our customers (this one is a painful one) want everything fixed but are resistant to change. But I agree that is the best option, Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like an Access data base will work. To overcome the issue of multipal users accessing it the same time I will split the DB. Thus giving me the front end and back end files. This should allow multipal users to access it without causing corruption.